# ICA Protocol with Streamed App's - XenApp

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I'm studying XenApp and I know that the ICA protocol is used when hosting an application to the XenApp server.

But does the ICA protocol is also used when streaming an application from xenapp to the client ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citrix app streaming is an application virtualization technology similar to Microsoft's App-V. A streamed (aka virtualized) application is packaged in a so-called profile which is transferred to the client for local execution. The transfer can happen over the following protocols:

- SMB (aka CIFS)
- HTTP
- HTTPS

Further reading: [Application Streaming Delivery and Profiling Best Practices](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/18183-102-641274/AppStreamingDeliveryProfilingBestPractices.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So when we configure printing for Citrix Plug-ins, it "works" only with hosted apps ?